# Angular GET request: preflight request aborted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.4.8 to get data from RESTfull API. For user authentication we decided to use custom HTTP header:

```
 var requestConfig = {
  headers: {
      "authorization-token": "A317C3D6-74B1-DA99-FE55-8141E95D3085"
  }
};
```

Now, I'm trying to make a GET request:

```
 $http.get(config.apiUrl+'/api/v1/orders/', requestConfig).success(function(data){
        table.orders = data;
    });
```

And see the following requests in Firebug:

[image]

I read that browsers make these pre-flight OPTIONS request if you trying to get data from another server. In my case Angular application is on 127.0.0.1:80 and Node.js server is on 127.0.0.1:6673, so it's cross-origin request as I understand

If you try to make OPTIONS request from curl you will get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin,  
Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, authorization-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 13
ETag: W/"d-7cCV5tLYsy8ebraCH4f8nQ"
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 19:56:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

So, my questions are:

1) Why OPTIONS request is not called if I remove custom HTTP header?

2) What is missing in OPTIONS response, why it's aborted?

UPD:

Here are headers from original GET request. I can not see OPTIONS headers though.

[image]

UPD2:

I was able to get this error message from Chrome dev tool for OPTIONS request:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Try to limit yourself to one question per question. It is hard to tell what answer to your second question is because your question lacks context. I'd guess it is because you are navigating away from the page, but there's no way to tell with the information you've provided.

Comment: Can you open the network tab in your devtools and show the headers, response, and request when you make the call from your browser?

Comment: @JoshBeam Thank you for response. I have updated my questions with request headers

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for answer. What information I need to add to the post?

Comment: Is that from Chrome? Usually I find the Chrome devtools Network tab a bit more helpful than other browsers lol :p not sure if you have it available. However, second question: have you tried clearing your cache? I believe browsers cache OPTIONS requests.

Comment: @JoshBeam First screenshot is from Firebug. I tried chrome and get this error message for OPTIONS request: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  Tried to clear cache - request still fails.

Comment: Connection refused suggests that you got the host name or ip address wrong or forgot to start the server.

Comment: Agreed with @Quentin. What do your server logs say, if anything?

Answer (score 0):

> Why OPTIONS request is not called if I remove custom HTTP header?

Custom HTTP headers are one of the triggers for requiring a preflight.

> In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
> - It sets **custom headers in the request** (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)